# Listing all Orders in an Admin Website in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build an Admin Control Panel different from the existing one in order to better view some of the orders made in an E-commerce Project.

I am trying to list all the orders made to be in a list view but I am getting the following error: `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I tried to fix it but I am not sure the root of it.

Here is the view.py which is already working to be viewed by users

```
class OrderList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = "user_orders.html"
    context_object_name = 'orders'
    paginate_by = 2
    ordering = ['-ordered_date']
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')
```

This is the view I am trying to create for admin only to consolidate the orders together

```
@staff_member_required
class Control_Order_List(ListView):
    model = Order
    template_name = "control_all_orders.html"
    context_object_name = 'orders'
    paginate_by = 2
    ordering = ['-ordered_date']
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Order.objects.filter(user=self.user, ordered=True).order_by('-ordered_date')
```

Here is the urls.py

```
app_name = 'newsletters'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('newsletter/', control_newsletter, name="control_newsletter"),
    path('control_all_orders', Control_Order_List,
         name="control_all_orders"),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('control_all_orders', Control_Order_List.as_view(), name="control_all_orders"),
]
```

You need to use the `.as_view()` attribute for class-based views in URLs.

**EDIT**

For class-based views, you must add decorators like this:

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(staff_member_required, name='dispatch')
class Control_Order_List(ListView):
    # ...
```

Here's what you did wrong:

```py
# Do NOT apply the decorator directly for classes, like
@staff_member_required
class AnyClassBasedView():
```

Your approach is only used for function-based views as adding the decorator directly will transform your view into a function. You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

Comment: Hi, I got a `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

Comment: @crimsonpython24     `path('control_all_orders', Control_Order_List,
         name="control_all_orders"),`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `path` as follows:

```
path('control_all_orders', Control_Order_List.as_view(),
     name="control_all_orders"),
```

I.e. adding `.as_view()`

If this doesn't solve your problem, please post the entire traceback.